# String Replace Java

Tags: java, string, kotlin, replace

I am trying to make a Hangman code in Java. I have a interface class with random words, that each time the program runs I pick a word from there. 
Now I made a string for control that copy's the value of the first string and I want to change all the letters with "_". The problem is that from what I found if I use replace all I can change only a letter. I tried to use it with a for to go throw all the letters in the alphabet but I could't use the initialisation in replace. It asked a letter. 
Is there a way (or a method) that I can change my word?

```
public class Main {
    static String rdword;
    static int n;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rd = new Random();

    n = rd.nextInt(3000);
    rdword= EnWords.words[n];
    String control = rdword;

    for (char i = 'a'; i < 'z'; i++ ) {
        control .replace (i, "_");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))?

Comment: One major problem with your code is that `String` is immutable, so `replace` cannot update the string, and instead returns the new string value, but your code doesn't use the return value. Your code would work if you changed statement to `control = control.replace(i, '_');`. Note also how the second parameter was changed to a `char`, so the [`replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) version of the method is called.

Comment: Why not just make a new string of the appropriate length made up of all underscores? I'm not a Java guy, but in c# you could do `new string('_', control.Length)`. I imagine something similar exists in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use regex instead of for loop like below snippet:

```
control = control.replaceAll("[a-z]", "_")
```